# "Rock TV" animated/live action series from the early to mid 80s

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

Riffling through my memory on another question, I was reminded of a series that aired in the States on broadcast (NBC, I think, though it may have been syndicated), probably Saturday mornings.  I seem to remember it being called "Rock TV" or "Wolfgang Rock TV".  However, I can find nothing on Wikipedia or IMDB about such a series.

It had an animated portion where the characters went to "The Flip Side" with the help of a DJ.  Interspersed between the animated portion, they would play current music videos (the era of the videos was 1983-84 and featured Madonna and The Police, etc.).

Could anyone tell me the exact name of this series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wolf Rock TV](http://www.toonarific.com/show.php?show_id=3965)

Description from Toonarific:

> Born with a face for cartoons, deejay icon Wolfman Jack stretched
>   himself into two dimensions to portray a mentor to three teens-Sarah,
>   Sunny, and Ricardo-and a bird named Bopper in this short-lived show.
>
> The Wolfman, who built his reputation in the 50's and 60's for playing
>   banned songs over Mexican border radio stations, had slowly become
>   more mainstream, especially with his cameo in the 1973 movie American
>   Graffiti. Now, he was a cartoon station manager, overseeing the three
>   kids as they ran a rock TV show featuring real live-action videos.
>   Although the kids dug the super keen Wolfman, the station manager, Mr.
>   Morris, was not exactly a fan.
>
> The show, a Dick Clark production, also featured a segment known as
>   “Wolf Rock News,” as well as “The Rock ‘n’ Roll Museum,” where
>   live-action interviews took place.
>
> In 1989, under the title Wolf Rock Power Hour, the show ran in
>   syndication with the similarly themed Kidd Video.

Answer (score 4):

This is [Kidd Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidd_Video):

> The title sequence explained the plot; Kidd Video and his band of the
>   same name (played by live-action performers in the first half of the
>   title sequence) were kidnapped by a villain named Master Blaster, and
>   transported to Master Blaster's home dimension, a cartoon world called
>   The Flipside. They were rescued by a fairy named Glitter, and
>   subsequently spent each episode of the series either helping to free
>   the denizens of the Flipside from Master Blaster's rule, or trying to
>   find a way back to the "real world". Master Blaster, who seemed to be
>   a cartoonization of a corrupt rock manager or music executive, flew
>   around the sky in his floating castle, which resembled a giant
>   jukebox.

Comment: Yes, this definitely has "The Flipside" I think I mashed the two together inadvertently.  I was looking for the Wolfman one, though.